# Ruby create Cipher key from preexisting key string

Tags: ruby, openssl

With the OpenSSL CLI I can encrypt values using just about any ASCII string I can find as long as it fits the lengths required by the encryption method.

For example:

```
printf 'flipflop' | openssl enc -K 2317823178123897237891232345345234524523452345 -iv 123789123789123789 -base64 -aes-256-cbc

Pd4+UEBW1RyTjARy1rpndQ==

printf 'Pd4+UEBW1RyTjARy1rpndQ==\n' | openssl enc -d -K 2317823178123897237891232345345234524523452345 -iv 123789123789123789 -base64 -aes-256-cbc

flipflop
```

However if I take that key and we run through this with Ruby:

```
require 'openssl'

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new 'AES-256-CBC'
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = "2317823178123897237891232345345234524523452345"
cipher.iv = "123789123789123789"
encrypted = cipher.update "flipflop" + cipher.final
puts encrypted

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new 'AES-256-CBC'
cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = "2317823178123897237891232345345234524523452345"
cipher.iv = "123789123789123789"
plain = cipher.update(encrypted) + cipher.final
puts plain

���ISq��Ҷ0�e�
crypt.rb:14:in `final': bad decrypt (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)
    from crypt.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

Also when I take the base64 from the openssl command I get the same bad decrypt:

```
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

clear = Base64.decode64("Pd4+UEBW1RyTjARy1rpndQ==")

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new 'AES-256-CBC'
cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = "2317823178123897237891232345345234524523452345"
cipher.iv = "123789123789123789"
plain = cipher.update(clear) + cipher.final
puts plain

crypt.rb:10:in `final': bad decrypt (OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError)
    from crypt.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

What I believe is happening here is that OpenSSL is converting my cipher key and IV one way, and ruby is doing it another. For example when you create a key using PBKDF2 you get a string of a bunch of hex values i.e.: "\x00\AF...".

Is that the issue at hand? That I need to convert my strings into a particular format? How do I do that? Is that not the issue?

Comment: Also note that OpenSSL changed default command line values at 1.1.0. Its causing a fair amount of trouble for folks who use `openssl enc` for 1.0.2 (or below) and then `openssl dec` for 1.1.0 and above. Also see [Decrypt old openssl files](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2017-February/005270.html) on the OpenSSL user list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There’s a couple of issues here.

Your Ruby round trip code isn’t working because of this line:

```
encrypted = cipher.update "flipflop" + cipher.final
```

It should be:

```
encrypted = cipher.update("flipflop") + cipher.final
```

This is giving a wrong encryption resulting in the `bad decrypt` error. Otherwise that code should work, although it is using different keys and ivs than the command line version. However, it will only work on old versions of Ruby and the OpenSSL bindings. The current version of Ruby’s OpenSSL lib checks the length of the `key` and `iv` provided and raise an exception if they are wrong. For aes-256-cbc they should be 32 and 16 bytes respectively.

The `-K` and `-iv` options of the `openssl enc` command accept hexadecimal encoded strings which it then decodes to the raw bytes. It also pads out these values with zero bytes until they are the right length.

Here’s how you can decrypt the command line encrypted string in Ruby:

```ruby
# Base64 cipher text from the question:
message = "Pd4+UEBW1RyTjARy1rpndQ=="
message = Base64.decode64(message)

key = "2317823178123897237891232345345234524523452345"
#Convert from hex to raw bytes:
key = [key].pack('H*')
#Pad with zero bytes to correct length:
key << ("\x00" * (32 - key.length))

iv ="123789123789123789"
#Convert from hex to raw bytes:
iv = [iv].pack('H*')
#Pad with zero bytes to correct length:
iv << ("\x00" * (16 - iv.length))

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-CBC')
cipher.decrypt
cipher.key = key
cipher.iv = iv
plain = cipher.update(message) + cipher.final
puts plain # => 'flipflop'
```

Comment: beautiful, I'll try this out in a second. Thanks for the info matt.